# How to prove that $n^{1/n}>(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}$ is equivalent to $n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

Found this inside an example in my analysis book. Can't  figure out why the two are equivalent and how to work out the algebra.

My question is:

- What is the algebra behind $n^{1/n}>(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}$ is equivalent to $n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$ (and how to prove it)?

Sorry if this is something basic, I'm just not being able to work out the algebra behind it.

EDIT: I think I need to take a break...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$n^{\frac{1}{n}}>(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$ it's
$$\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n(n+1)}>\left((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^{n(n+1)}$$ or
$$n^{n+1}>(n+1)^{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^{n(n+1)}$ is strictly increasing for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^6$ is strictly increasing ?

Comment: It means $x\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

powering by $n(n+1)$ we get
$$n^{n+1}>(n+1)^n$$
and it follows that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<n$$ for $n\geq 2$