# Prove that $2022^{2023}>2023^{2022}$

Tags: functions, inequality

I have considered a function $f (x) = x^{x+1}-(x+1)^x$ , with $f : [2022;+\infty)\to R$ .

I have made the signs table for the derivative of the function, assuming x on the respective interval. The sign of the derivative is positive on the interval $[2022;+\infty)$, which means the function is increasing.

I have calculated $f(2022)$ which is $2022^{2023}-2023^{2022}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$, which is $\infty$.

In conclusion, I found the monotony for the function, but still haven't proved the inequality.

Any serious answear is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the derivative of $x^{1/x}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2595833/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1656665/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77935/42969

Comment: Hint : $$x^{x+1}-(x+1)^x=x^x(x-(\frac{x+1}{x})^x)$$ and $$(\frac{x+1}{x})^x<e$$ for $x\ge 1$